# Getting stucked(blank page) on process page over and over again

Tags: php

i have a problem with my website , problem is with this one:
When i try to login and i enter a correct login info,i am keep getting stucked on process_login page and header dont want to redirect me back to index page...This is only happening on my webpage , on localhost everything is going perfectly fine..
Code:

login modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="login" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <center><div class="modal-header"> 
                             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>   
                            <div class="alert alert-info">Login page</div>
                        </div></center>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                           <form role="form" action="process_login.php" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="exampleInputUsername">Username</label>
                              <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username_login" placeholder="Enter username"><span id="span_username_login"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                              <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password_login" placeholder="Password"><span id="span_password_login"></span><br/>
                            </div>
                               <a href="#recover" data-toggle="modal" ><p>I've forgotten my password</a></p>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                            <center><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Sign in"/></center>
                         </div>
                            </form>
                    </div>   
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

process_login.php page

```
  <?php
require_once 'includes/initialize.php';
require_once 'classes/database.php';
require_once 'classes/bcrypt.php';
require_once 'classes/user.php';


    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

            $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username' , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password' , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

            //if input fields ain't filled , redirecting back to index page
            if(empty($username) || empty($password))        
            {                                                       
                $_SESSION['emptyfields'] = '';
                header("Location: index.php");

            }
            //if that particular username doesnt exist in database , redirecting back                    to index page
            if($userclass->userExists($username) == false)
            {
                $_SESSION['usernamedoesntexist'] = '';
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
            //if that particular email isnt confirmed yet , redirecting back to index page
            if($userclass->emailConfirmed($username) == false)
            {
                $_SESSION['emailnotconfirmed'] = '';   
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
            if($userclass->banned($username) == false)
            {
               //if that particular username is banned , redirecting back to index page
               $_SESSION['banned'] = '';    
               header("Location: index.php");

            }    


            $login = $userclass->login($username, $password);
            if($login == false)
            {
                $_SESSION['errorwithlogin'] = '';       //incorect username - password combo
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['user_auth'] = TRUE;          //corect username - password combo
                $_SESSION['user_id'] =  $login;

                $_SESSION['loginsuccessfull'] = '';
                header("Location: index.php");

            }



    }
        else
        {
             $_SESSION['errorwithprocessing'] = '';
             header("Location: index.php");
        }    

?>
<?php
unset($_SESSION['errorwithprocessing']);
unset($_SESSION['loginsuccessfull']);
unset($_SESSION['errorwithlogin']);
unset($_SESSION['banned']);
unset($_SESSION['emailnotconfirmed']);
unset($_SESSION['usernamedoesntexist']);
unset($_SESSION['emptyfields']);
?>
```

class user.php page(rows that have connection with logging in)

```
public function login($username, $password)
    {
        global $db;
        global $bcrypt;

        $stm = $db->connection->prepare("SELECT `user_id`,`password`  FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?");    

        $stm->bindValue(1, $username);

        try
        {        
                    $stm->execute();
                    $data = $stm->fetch();      
                    $stored_password = $data['password'];       
                    $id = (int) $data['user_id'];   

                    if($bcrypt->verify($password, $stored_password) === true)           
                    {   
                        return $id;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Any help is welcome , thanks in advance..

Comment: Do not forget to add `exit;` after the `header` if no further code should be executed. And enable output of error messages.

Comment: Well, you should begin by adding `exit;` after the redirects (e.g. `header('Location: test.php'); exit;`). PHP will continue reading the code, so you have to stop it when redirecting.

Comment: Lots of extra code in the process_login.php script BTW. No matter what happens you want to send the user back to index.php so you might as well just add it once after the last `else` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see I am assuming you are starting a session before you get to the redirecting code. Maybe in one of your included files? Whatever the case you will want to call all `header()` functions before calling `session_start()`. From my experience, not doing so caused unpredictable results depending on the version of PHP I was running and the server.

However, I do understand that this is not always an option, and with this in mind, I use the following code as a workaround for `header("Location:index.php")`; This will do the redirect using javascript.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="index.php";</script>';
```

Comment: session_start() was in my initialize file ,but nvm mate , 1000 thanks to you... This worked perfectly fine for me , everything is ok now...Thanks once again..

Comment: Awesome, happy to hear